# Ajax jQuery plugin with Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, jquery-plugins, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using Ajax jQuery plugin jars with Struts 2. I have used Ajax select tag populate the list but list is not populating. if I used `<sj:autocompleter>` tag it works fine.

**This is my code:**

```xml
<sj:select name="countryId" list="countryList" listKey="id" listValue="name" 
                headerKey="" headerValue="--Select Country--" 
                onchange="document.forms[0].action='city_countryChange'; document.forms[0].submit(); return true;" 
                required="required"></sj:select>
```

what's wrong with `<sj:select>` tag?

Comment: show your action code & struts result configuration (xml/annotation)

Answer (score 0):

When you used [`<sj:autocompleter>`](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag), and you say that it works fine, you have used `href` attribute. `<sj:select>`'s `href` attribute also could be used to populate HTML `<select>` tag which is rendered by the `<sj:select>`. The set of attributes is slightly different for each tag, and a `href` attribute is also different than in HTML `<select>` tag.

The `href` attribute is available and used by both tags and you should supply JSON result returned by the action which populate the `<sj:select>` tag. But if you use `autocomplete=true` attribute then `<sj:select>` behave like `<sj:autocompleter>` and generate `input` tag  instead of `<select>` tag. You should define which HTML tag you need for the output.

Playing with attributes could cardinal change the rendered HTML. If you use `list` attribute with the `<sj:select>` tag and don't use `autocomplete` attribute then simple `<select>` with `options` will be rendered when the result is executed. It's the same like ordinal `<s:select>` is used. Thus you should provide the getter for the `list` attribute value like

```
public List<Country> getCountryList() {
  return countryList;
}
```

The `Country` bean should contain `id` and `name` properties, so it also accessible to OGNL.

Comment: Okay but i am not able to get @Actions annotaion, don't know why.  The thing is i am using JSON-plugin 2.3.1 jar file with Sturts2-core 2.3.14 .

Comment: You should not use different versions of framework libraries.

Comment: Then Which version of plugin should i use with Struts2-core-2.3.14 jar??

Comment: struts2-json-plugin-2.3.14.jar

Comment: Struts2-json-plugin-2.3.13 jar version also used but in @Action annotation there is only INPUT,OUTPUT and fault attributes are there.

Comment: I have seen example  in this link https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag they are using Value and result attribut.

Comment: Ok, if you want to use them then you should return JSON result.